# Change formatting from float to int, in columns of a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table, unfortunately I am unable to cast the column to an int value due to NaN values, and it represents a year in the data.  Is there a way to use a function to manipulate the columns (lambda?) in the creation of the pivot table?

```
submissions_by_country = df_maa_lu.pivot_table(index=["COUNTRY_DISPLAY_LABEL"], columns=["APPROVAL_YEAR"], values='LU_NUMBER_NO_SUFFIX', aggfunc='nunique', fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@smackenzie,
Is it possible to replace the value and recast. For e.g: Assuming your dataframe is called df

```py
   df.replace(to_replace =np.nan, value =0.) 
   df.astype(float)
```

If retaining `np.nan` is important, you can replace with a unique value like -999. and then upon changing the datatype, replace it again..

If you just wanted to updated the value in a column i.e. pd.Series instead of the entire dataframe, you could try that like this, not sure if dictionaries would allow NaN to be the key though:

```py
   df['Afghanistan'] = w['Afghanistan'].map({np.NaN: 0.0})
```

Can you post a sample dataset to work with?

Comment: Can I do this in place for a series, not the entire frame.  My question was more around how clever can you be in the "columns" option of the pivot table, i.e. can you put an expression in here to format the columns here, rather than fixing it in the frame.